# MySQL to JSON, only loads first row

Tags: php, mysql, json, file

I'm trying to fetch all rows from a table using MySQL and store it as a JSON-file. Right now the only thing that's being stored in the JSON-file is the first row from the table.

Here's the code:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$res_sql = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
$arr = array();


if(mysql_num_rows($res_sql) > 0){

    while($row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_sql)){

        $arr =  $row_sql;

        $json = json_encode($arr);
        $file = 'table.json';
        file_put_contents($file, $json);

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$res_sql = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
$arr = array();


if(mysql_num_rows($res_sql) > 0){

    while($row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_sql)){

        $arr[] =  $row_sql;

    }

     $json = json_encode($arr);
     $file = 'table.json';
     file_put_contents($file, $json);    
}
```

Make `file_put_contents` outside the loop

Comment: It works! I had tried to put it outside before to, but it didn't work for some reason. I think the "[]" did it.

I also had to add `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` because of this error: `Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes)`

I know I probably should edit php.ini instead of throwing it in like this straight into the code, but it'll due for now.

Comment: @user2479698 Good info.! Noted.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:-

```
 while($row_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_sql)){

            $arr[] =  $row_sql;
     }
    $json = json_encode($arr);
    $file = 'table.json';
    file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

Comment: But `$arr` is already declared as `$arr = array()` why again `$arr[]` .?

Comment: @hemnath mouli $arr[] is not declaration, it's adding value to array